# urllib2 gives 401 while curl works (without auth)

Tags: python, urllib2

```
curl -H "Content-type:application/json" -k https://abx,xyz.com/api/rawquery -d '{"query":"xyz"}
```

WORKS, but fetching the data with urllib2 does not as below.

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import json

url = "https://abx.xyz.com/api/rawquery"
headers = {"Content-type" :"application/json"}
values = {'query': 'xyz'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

OUTPUT:
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Comment: try to use `requests` instead, it's better anyways.

Comment: Use http://httpbin.org/ to find difference between `curl` and `urllib` request.